# Comprobar que dos dispositivos estén listos para empezar. Bluetooth Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Buenas, estoy haciendo un aplicación/juego en la cuál se conectan dos dispositivos vía bluetooth para jugar. La parte de conectarse y enviar valores y mostrarla para cada dispositivo ya esta hecho.

Cuando se logró establecer la conexión bluetooth entre ambos, les aparece un `EditText` y un `Button`, se debe introducir un número y presionar el botón, el juego debería de empezar cuando ambos presionaron el botón, ese es mi problema, no se como comprobar que ambos dispositivos han presionado el botón para así empezar el juego.

Les dejo el código:

```
public class InicioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView estado;
private EditText numero;
private ListView listaResultados;
private ListView listaNumsContrario;
private TextView mostrarNumElegido;
private TextView tv_resultado;
private TextView tv_msjInicio;
private View btnListo;

private Dialog dialog;
private ArrayAdapter<String> numContrarioAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> numsContrario;
private ArrayAdapter<String> resultadoAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> resultados;

private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

ActionBar actionBar;

private String numElegido = "";
private String numRival = "";
private int listos = 0;
private boolean empezar = false;

public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
public static final String DEVICE_OBJECT = "device_name";

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
private ServicioBluetooth servicioBluetooth;
private BluetoothDevice connectingDevice;
private ArrayAdapter<String> discoveredDevicesAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    findViewsByIds();

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    //check device support bluetooth or not
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No soporta Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }


    //set chat adapter
    resultados = new ArrayList<>();
    resultadoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.row_text, resultados);
    listaResultados.setAdapter(resultadoAdapter);

    numsContrario = new ArrayList<>();
    numContrarioAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.row_text, numsContrario);
    listaNumsContrario.setAdapter(numContrarioAdapter);
}

private void findViewsByIds() {
    estado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_estado);
    listaResultados = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_resultados);
    btnListo = findViewById(R.id.btn_listo);
    numero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_numeroElegido);
    listaNumsContrario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_numsContrario);
    mostrarNumElegido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_numElegido);
    tv_msjInicio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_msj_inicio);
    tv_resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_resultado);


    btnListo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String num = numero.getText().toString();
            if (num.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(InicioActivity.this, "Ingresa un número", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String resultado = verficarNumero(num);

            if (!resultado.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(InicioActivity.this, resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            sendMessage(num);
            numero.setText("");
        }
    });
}



private void activarVisivilidad(){
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case ServicioBluetooth.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        actionBar.setSubtitle("Conectado: " + connectingDevice.getName());
                        empezarJuego();
                        break;
                    case ServicioBluetooth.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        actionBar.setSubtitle("Conectando...");
                        break;
                    case ServicioBluetooth.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case ServicioBluetooth.STATE_NONE:
                        actionBar.setSubtitle("No conectado");
                        terminarJuego();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                if (numElegido.equals("")){
                    numElegido = writeMessage;
                    mostrarNumElegido.setText(numElegido);
                }
                else{
                    resultados.add(compararNumeros(writeMessage));
                    resultadoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                if (numRival.equals("")){
                    numRival = readMessage;
                    listos++;
                    Toast.makeText(InicioActivity.this, "listos: " + listos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    numsContrario.add(readMessage);
                    numContrarioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT:
                connectingDevice = msg.getData().getParcelable(DEVICE_OBJECT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + connectingDevice.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString("toast"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

private void showPrinterPickDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bluetooth);


    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    //Initializing bluetooth adapters
    ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    discoveredDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    //locate listviews and attatch the adapters
    ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
    ListView listView2 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.discoveredDeviceList);
    listView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesAdapter);
    listView2.setAdapter(discoveredDevicesAdapter);

    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            pairedDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    } else {
        pairedDevicesAdapter.add("No hay dispositivos");
    }

    //Handling listview item click event
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            if (info.equals("No hay dispositivos")){
                return;
            }
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            connectToDevice(address);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            if (info.equals("No hay dispositivos")){
                return;
            }
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            connectToDevice(address);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

private void setEstado(String s) {
    estado.setText(s);
}

private void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
    servicioBluetooth.connect(device);
}



private String verficarNumero(String num){
    String primerNum = num.substring(0,1);
    String comparado;
    String comparando;
    if (num.length() < 4){
        return "Debe tener 4 digitos";
    }
    if (primerNum.equals("0")){
        return "No puede empezar por 0";
    }
    for (int i=0; i<num.length()-1; i++){
        comparado = num.substring(i,i+1);
        for (int j=i+1; j<num.length(); j++){
            comparando = num.substring(j,j+1);
            if (comparado.equals(comparando)) {
                return "No debe haber números repetidos";
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                servicioBluetooth = new ServicioBluetooth(this, handler);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth desactivado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (servicioBluetooth.getEstado() != ServicioBluetooth.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se perdió la conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (message.length() > 0) {
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        servicioBluetooth.write(send);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
    } else {
        servicioBluetooth = new ServicioBluetooth(this, handler);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (servicioBluetooth != null) {
        if (servicioBluetooth.getEstado() == ServicioBluetooth.STATE_NONE) {
            servicioBluetooth.start();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (servicioBluetooth != null)
        servicioBluetooth.stop();
}

private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            if (discoveredDevicesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                discoveredDevicesAdapter.add("No hay dispositivos");
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.top_bar_buttons, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.conectar_bt:
            showPrinterPickDialog();
            return true;
        case R.id.visible_bt:
            activarVisivilidad();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void empezarJuego(){
    tv_msjInicio.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    tv_resultado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnListo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    estado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    numero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listaNumsContrario.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listaResultados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mostrarNumElegido.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void terminarJuego(){
    tv_msjInicio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    tv_resultado.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnListo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    estado.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    numero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    listaNumsContrario.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    listaResultados.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mostrarNumElegido.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private String compararNumeros(String num){
    String comparado;
    String comparando;
    int bien = 0;
    int regular = 0;
    int mal = 0;
    String res = "";

    for (int i=0; i<num.length(); i++){
        comparado = num.substring(i, i+1);
        res += comparado + " ";
        for (int j=0; j<numRival.length();j++){
            comparando = numRival.substring(j,j+1);
            if (comparado.equals(comparando)){
                if (i == j){
                    bien++;
                }
                else
                    regular++;
            }
        }
    }
    mal = 4 - (bien + regular);
    return res + "  -   " + bien + "b  " + regular + "r  " + mal + "m";
}
}
```

-

```
public class ServicioBluetooth {

private static final String APP_NAME = "Adivinar los números";
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("mi-uuid");

private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private final Handler handler;
private AcceptThread acceptThread;
private ConnectThread connectThread;
private ReadWriteThread connectedThread;
private int estado;

static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;


public ServicioBluetooth(Context context, Handler handler) {
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    estado = STATE_NONE;

    this.handler = handler;
}

// Set the current state of the chat connection
private synchronized void setEstado(int state) {
    this.estado = state;

    handler.obtainMessage(InicioActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

// get current connection state
public synchronized int getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

// start service
public synchronized void start() {
    // Cancel any thread
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread.cancel();
        connectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any running thresd
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    setEstado(STATE_LISTEN);
    if (acceptThread == null) {
        acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        acceptThread.start();
    }
}

// initiate connection to remote device
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Cancel any thread
    if (estado == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (connectThread != null) {
            connectThread.cancel();
            connectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel running thread
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    connectThread.start();
    setEstado(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

// manage Bluetooth connection
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Cancel the thread
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread.cancel();
        connectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel running thread
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    if (acceptThread != null) {
        acceptThread.cancel();
        acceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    connectedThread = new ReadWriteThread(socket);
    connectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(InicioActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(InicioActivity.DEVICE_OBJECT, device);
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    setEstado(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

// stop all threads
public synchronized void stop() {
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread.cancel();
        connectThread = null;
    }

    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    if (acceptThread != null) {
        acceptThread.cancel();
        acceptThread = null;
    }
    setEstado(STATE_NONE);
}

public void write(byte[] out) {
    ReadWriteThread r;
    synchronized (this) {
        if (estado != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        r = connectedThread;
    }
    r.write(out);
}

private void connectionFailed() {
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(InicioActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("toast", "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    ServicioBluetooth.this.start();
}

private void connectionLost() {
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(InicioActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("toast", "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    ServicioBluetooth.this.start();
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

// runs while listening for incoming connections
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(APP_NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        serverSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket;
        while (estado != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (ServicioBluetooth.this) {
                    switch (estado) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate
                            // new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

// runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket socket;
    private final BluetoothDevice device;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            socket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (ServicioBluetooth.this) {
            connectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(socket, device);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

// runs during a connection with a remote device
private class ReadWriteThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ReadWriteThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        this.bluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        inputStream = tmpIn;
        outputStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                handler.obtainMessage(InicioActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1,
                        buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                ServicioBluetooth.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // write to OutputStream
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(buffer);
            handler.obtainMessage(InicioActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1,
                    buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hola Juan, ¿haz realizado una parte de esto?, si es así agrega tu código, este tipo de preguntas desgraciadamente no son bien recibidas y desgraciadamente terminan con puntuación negativa. Revisa por favor [ask] te sugiero realices el [tour].

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo, ahí edite la pregunta y agregué mi código.